# I need to do a mongo lookup on data, but want an empty array where no data is found

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am new to mongo and I've got a query that I am running as seen below:

```
db.getCollection('equityprice_input').aggregate([
        
        {'$match': {'mrsBusinessDate': '2022-05-05', 'instrument': 'other', 'sourceSystem': 'bloomberg', 'mrsTime': '17:00:00', 'dataType': 'price'}},
        
        {'$lookup': {'from': 'equityprice_input', 'localField': 'data.securities', 'foreignField': 'data.securities', 'as': 'staticData'}}, 
        
        {'$project': {'_id': 1, 'mrsBusinessDate': 1, 'mrsTime': 1, 'category': 1, 'instrument': 1, 'label': 1, 'sourceSystem': 1, 'mrsDescription': 1, 'data': 1, 'staticData.data': 1, 'staticData.dataType': 1}}, 
        
        {'$unwind': '$staticData'}, 
        
        {'$match': {'staticData.dataType': 'static'}}, 
        
        {'$project': {'_id': 1, 'mrsBusinessDate': 1, 'mrsTime': 1, 'category': 1, 'instrument': 1, 'label': 1, 'sourceSystem': 1, 'mrsDescription': 1, 'data': 1, 'staticData.data': 1}}
])
```

The above query returns data that has `'staticData.dataType': 'static'` and does not return if an entry does not. I need it to return an empty array when there is no `'staticData.dataType': 'static'`.

I've tried a few things, but my limited knowledge of mongo makes it hard to know where I am going wrong. Hoping that someone can assist.

Output looks as below when there is `'staticData.dataType': 'static'`:
[image]

What I want when there is no `'staticData.dataType': 'static'`:

[image]

Comment: where you do you want to return an empty array? like this `staticData: { dataType: [], data: {} }`

Answer (score 0):

You can put a `.toArray()` at the end of your whole aggregation to return that.

```
db.getCollection('equityprice_input').aggregate([
        
        {'$match': {'mrsBusinessDate': '2022-05-05', 'instrument': 'other', 'sourceSystem': 'bloomberg', 'mrsTime': '17:00:00', 'dataType': 'price'}},
        
        {'$lookup': {'from': 'equityprice_input', 'localField': 'data.securities', 'foreignField': 'data.securities', 'as': 'staticData'}}, 
        
        {'$project': {'_id': 1, 'mrsBusinessDate': 1, 'mrsTime': 1, 'category': 1, 'instrument': 1, 'label': 1, 'sourceSystem': 1, 'mrsDescription': 1, 'data': 1, 'staticData.data': 1, 'staticData.dataType': 1}}, 
        
        {'$unwind': '$staticData'}, 
        
        {'$match': {'staticData.dataType': 'static'}}, 
        
        {'$project': {'_id': 1, 'mrsBusinessDate': 1, 'mrsTime': 1, 'category': 1, 'instrument': 1, 'label': 1, 'sourceSystem': 1, 'mrsDescription': 1, 'data': 1, 'staticData.data': 1}}
]).toArray()
```

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/cursor.toArray/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your logic and requirements correctly, you can get your desired output by replacing the last `"$match"` with a conditional `"$set"`.  Here's the full query.

```js
db.getCollection('equityprice_input').aggregate([
{'$match': {'mrsBusinessDate': '2022-05-05', 'instrument': 'other', 'sourceSystem': 'bloomberg', 'mrsTime': '17:00:00', 'dataType': 'price'}},
{'$lookup': {'from': 'equityprice_input', 'localField': 'data.securities', 'foreignField': 'data.securities', 'as': 'staticData'}}, 
{'$project': {'_id': 1, 'mrsBusinessDate': 1, 'mrsTime': 1, 'category': 1, 'instrument': 1, 'label': 1, 'sourceSystem': 1, 'mrsDescription': 1, 'data': 1, 'staticData.data': 1, 'staticData.dataType': 1}}, 
{'$unwind': '$staticData'}, 
{"$set": {"staticData.data": {"$cond": [ {"$eq": ["$staticData.dataType", "static"]}, "$staticData.data", [] ]}}},        
{'$project': {'_id': 1, 'mrsBusinessDate': 1, 'mrsTime': 1, 'category': 1, 'instrument': 1, 'label': 1, 'sourceSystem': 1, 'mrsDescription': 1, 'data': 1, 'staticData.data': 1}}
])
```

A toy [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-LQ_3NvxqGE) example demonstrates the idea.

Or if you want `"staticData": []` instead of `"staticData": {"data": []}`, replace the `"$set"` with:

```js
{"$set": {"staticData": {"$cond": [ {"$eq": ["$staticData.dataType", "static"]}, "$staticData", [] ]}}},
```